# How to catch multiple exceptions in one line? (in the "except" block)

Tags: python, exception

I know that I can do:

```
try:
    # do something that may fail
except:
    # do this if ANYTHING goes wrong
```

I can also do this:

```
try:
    # do something that may fail
except IDontLikeYouException:
    # say please
except YouAreTooShortException:
    # stand on a ladder
```

But if I want to do the same thing inside two different exceptions, the best I can think of right now is to do this:

```
try:
    # do something that may fail
except IDontLikeYouException:
    # say please
except YouAreBeingMeanException:
    # say please
```

Is there any way that I can do something like this (since the action to take in both exceptions is to `say please`):

```
try:
    # do something that may fail
except IDontLikeYouException, YouAreBeingMeanException:
    # say please
```

Now this really won't work, as it matches the syntax for:

```
try:
    # do something that may fail
except Exception, e:
    # say please
```

So, my effort to catch the two distinct exceptions doesn't exactly come through.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Note that in Python 3, the latter is no longer valid syntax.

Comment: Your first code snippet triggered me a bit - see https://www.wilfred.me.uk/blog/2013/11/03/no-naked-excepts/

Answer (score 5085, accepted):

From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a parenthesized tuple, for example

```
except (IDontLikeYouException, YouAreBeingMeanException) as e:
    pass
```

Or, for Python 2 only:

```
except (IDontLikeYouException, YouAreBeingMeanException), e:
    pass
```

Separating the exception from the variable with a comma will still work in Python 2.6 and 2.7, but is now deprecated and does not work in Python 3; now you should be using `as`.

Comment: Is it possible to store desired exceptions in an iterable, and then catch the iterable? I'm trying to turn a list of warnings into errors using `warnings.filterwarnings`, and I don't want to have to specify the list of warnings twice.

Comment: I did try it... with a `list`, and it resulted in a `TypeError`. Looks like the errors must be in a `tuple` for catching to work as expected.

Comment: It was unclear whether the "parenthesized tuple" was merely syntactical  or that a bona fide tuple was required. "Parenthesized" is misleading because you may create a tuple without parentheses elsewhere and then use it in the `except` line. It is only necessarily parenthesized if created in the `except` line.

Comment: Anything parenthesized in python is a tuple

Comment: @JosephBani, what about generator expressions?

Comment: @JosephBani That's not true at all. In `2 + (x * 2)`, `(x * 2)` is certainly not a tuple. Parentheses are a general grouping construct. The defining characteristic of a tuple is that it contains a *comma* -- see [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple): "Note that it is actually the comma which makes a tuple, not the parentheses."

Comment: When you're not actually using the `e` (as in this case) you can just drop the `as e` or `, e` and then python 2 and 3 are the same ;)

Comment: So why doesn't (except ValueError OR IndexError:) work? This is what I originally tried, but it seemed like only the first error was getting looked at.

Comment: @ChrisNorris: `or` is tricky. In that example `IndexError` wouldn't be tied to anything so it would simply be ignored.

Comment: @BallpointBen try: `print(type(('foo', 'bar')))`, should give you `tuple`. BTW: This is also how you can test your program units (when writing on such lexers/parsers).

Answer (score 525):

> ### How do I catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block)

Do this:

```
try:
    may_raise_specific_errors():
except (SpecificErrorOne, SpecificErrorTwo) as error:
    handle(error) # might log or have some other default behavior...
```

The parentheses are required due to older syntax that used the commas to assign the error object to a name. The `as` keyword is used for the assignment. You can use any name for the error object, I prefer `error` personally.

### Best Practice

To do this in a manner currently and forward compatible with Python, you need to separate the Exceptions with commas and wrap them with parentheses to differentiate from earlier syntax that assigned the exception instance to a variable name by following the Exception type to be caught with a comma.

Here's an example of simple usage:

```
import sys

try:
    mainstuff()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError): # the parens are necessary
    sys.exit(0)
```

I'm specifying only these exceptions to avoid hiding bugs, which if I encounter I expect the full stack trace from.

This is documented here: https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

You can assign the exception to a variable, (`e` is common, but you might prefer a more verbose variable if you have long exception handling or your IDE only highlights selections larger than that, as mine does.) The instance has an args attribute. Here is an example:

```
import sys

try:
    mainstuff()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError) as err: 
    print(err)
    print(err.args)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Note that in Python 3, the `err` object falls out of scope when the `except` block is concluded.

### Deprecated

You may see code that assigns the error with a comma. This usage, the only form available in Python 2.5 and earlier, is deprecated, and if you wish your code to be forward compatible in Python 3, you should update the syntax to use the new form:

```
import sys

try:
    mainstuff()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError), err: # don't do this in Python 2.6+
    print err
    print err.args
    sys.exit(0)
```

If you see the comma name assignment in your codebase, and you're using Python 2.5 or higher, switch to the new way of doing it so your code remains compatible when you upgrade.

### The `suppress` context manager

The accepted answer is really 4 lines of code, minimum:

```
try:
    do_something()
except (IDontLikeYouException, YouAreBeingMeanException) as e:
    pass
```

The `try`, `except`, `pass` lines can be handled in a single line with the [suppress context manager, available in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(IDontLikeYouException, YouAreBeingMeanException):
     do_something()
```

So when you want to `pass` on certain exceptions, use `suppress`.

Comment: Good addition of `suppress`, a lot more readable than just doing `pass` on `except`

Comment: Can you log the exception and then pass it outside the with context manager?

Comment: @Mache: I do not find the suppress() syntax more readable personally. But maybe it’s matter of habit. Moreover, isn’t the import of this function from another library, for such a simple use, a useless overhead?

Answer (score 73):

From [Python documentation -> 8.3 Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> A `try` statement may have more than one except clause, to specify
>   handlers for different exceptions. At most one handler will be
>   executed. Handlers only handle exceptions that occur in the
>   corresponding try clause, not in other handlers of the same try
>   statement. An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a
>   parenthesized tuple, for example:
>
> ```
> except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
>     pass
> ```
>
> Note that the parentheses around this tuple are required, because
>   except `ValueError, e:` was the syntax used for what is normally
>   written as `except ValueError as e:` in modern Python (described
>   below). The old syntax is still supported for backwards compatibility.
>   This means `except RuntimeError, TypeError` is not equivalent to
>   `except (RuntimeError, TypeError):` but to `except RuntimeError as`
>   `TypeError:` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 61):

If you frequently use a large number of exceptions, you can pre-define a tuple, so you don't have to re-type them many times.

```
#This example code is a technique I use in a library that connects with websites to gather data

ConnectErrs  = (URLError, SSLError, SocketTimeoutError, BadStatusLine, ConnectionResetError)

def connect(url, data):
    #do connection and return some data
    return(received_data)

def some_function(var_a, var_b, ...):
    try: o = connect(url, data)
    except ConnectErrs as e:
        #do the recovery stuff
    blah #do normal stuff you would do if no exception occurred
```

**NOTES:**

1. If you, also, need to catch other exceptions than those in the
   pre-defined tuple, you will need to define another except block.
2. If you just cannot tolerate a global variable, define it in main()
   and pass it around where needed...

Answer (score 34):

One of the way to do this is..

```
try:
   You do your operations here;
   ......................
except(Exception1[, Exception2[,...ExceptionN]]]):
   If there is any exception from the given exception list, 
   then execute this block.
   ......................
else:
   If there is no exception then execute this block.
```

and another way is to create method which performs task executed by `except` block and call it through all of the `except` block that you write..

```
try:
   You do your operations here;
   ......................
except Exception1:
    functionname(parameterList)
except Exception2:
    functionname(parameterList)
except Exception3:
    functionname(parameterList)
else:
   If there is no exception then execute this block. 

def functionname( parameters ):
   //your task..
   return [expression]
```

I know that second one is not the best way to do this, but i'm just showing number of ways to do this thing.

Comment: I'm using the second one because I have two different exceptions that each need to be processed differently. Is there something wrong with doing it that way?

Comment: @majikman The second method with multiple clauses each calling the same function is not the best when you're trying to not repeat yourself and doing the same thing for two exceptions. (See the other answers for the right way to do that). However, having multiple `except` clauses is normal when you want to handle the exceptions differently.

Comment: The second way is actually awesome

Answer (score 21):

As of Python 3.11 you can take advantage of the `except*` clause that is used to handle multiple exceptions.

PEP-654 introduced a new standard exception type called `ExceptionGroup` that corresponds to a group of exceptions that are being propagated together. The `ExceptionGroup` can be handled using a new `except*` syntax. The `*` symbol indicates that multiple exceptions can be handled by each `except*` clause.

---

For example, you can handle multiple exceptions

```
try:
    raise ExceptionGroup('Example ExceptionGroup', (
        TypeError('Example TypeError'),
        ValueError('Example ValueError'),
        KeyError('Example KeyError'),
        AttributeError('Example AttributeError')
    ))
except* TypeError:
    ...
except* ValueError as e:
    ...
except* (KeyError, AttributeError) as e:
    ...
```

---

For more details see [PEP-654](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/).