# Idiomatic way to collect & report multiple exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception, logging

**What have people used to catch, log, and report multiple data validation errors at once in Python?**

I'm building an application in Python 3 that first validates input data and then processes it. Reporting errors in the first step is part of the intended functionality of the program, so I don't want my validator to give up on the first exception. In particular, the data are tabular and I want  be able to return -- rather than raise -- an exception for each line of the table that does not validate.

A [forum discussion from a couple of years ago](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t722411-idiomatic-way-to-collect-and-report-multiple-exceptions.html) contemplates multiple solutions, including the following, which seems the cleanest to me:

```py
errors = []
for item in data:
    try:
        process(item)
    except ValidationError as e:
        errors.append(e)
if errors:
    raise MultipleValidationErrors(errors)
```

where the `MultipleValidationErrors` class would have an appropriate `__str__` method to list useful information about all the `ValidationErrors` in it.

Others recommend using the `traceback` module, but since the exceptions I want to catch are data validation errors rather than program errors, that seems inappropriate. Getting the `logging` module involved might be appropriate, though.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block) would help

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: that question is about catching multiple types of exceptions; this one is about catching multiple instances of the same exception type.

Comment: The code you list will work, if it does what you want, or you could use the traceback module to provide even more information, as you mention.  Alternatively you could save the exception object in a data structure for later use, or do many other things.  It all depends on what your requirements for responding to the exceptions are, which are not clear from your question.

Comment: @Aaron-Watters My goal is that once I've processed all the incoming data, I can print all of the errors, one line of error per line of incoming data. (More specifically, since I'm writing the library and user interface separately, my library would return the data structure of errors to the user interface which could do whatever it wants. A CLI would print the errors to `stdout`, whereas a GUI would provide some interactive table interface.)

Comment: Too bad the forum post didn't actually discuss multiple solutions. Instead it was the OP solution and then ratholing on tabs vs. spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used this idiom in both C++ and Python. It's the cleanest solution that I know of when what you want is an exception, rather than a log message. The downside to it is that the combined exception takes up linear space in general, which can be problematic when processing large datasets with many errors.

Comment: This answer seems to be missing its context when read standalone.  I don't know what idiom you are referring to.

Comment: @ThorSummoner I think larsmans is referring to how the OP collects the different exceptions in a list, and then raises a single exception that contains the list.

Answer (score 2):

I follow the list of errors approach but contain it in an object like this:

```
class Multi_Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self, errors: list[Exception]) -> None:
        self.errors = errors
        super().__init__(self.errors)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "\n".join([str(x) for x in self.errors])
```

Answer (score 0):

### ExceptionGroup (Python 3.11 and above)

```py
try:
    raise ExceptionGroup("Validation error", [AssertionError("A"), AssertionError("b"), ValueError(654)])
except ExceptionGroup as eg:
    for err in eg.exceptions:
        if isinstance(err, AssertionError):
            print("Handling AssertionError:", err)
        elif isinstance(err, ValueError):
            print("Handling ValueError:", err)
```

Or:

```py
try:
    raise ExceptionGroup("Validation error", [AssertionError("A"), AssertionError("b"), ValueError(654)])
except* AssertionError as eg:
    for err in eg.exceptions:
        print("Handling AssertionError:", err)
except* ValueError as eg:
    for err in eg.exceptions:
        print("Handling ValueError:", err)
```

Output:

```
Handling AssertionError: A
Handling AssertionError: b
Handling ValueError: 654
```

### Something custom

For example, see what Django did with the [`ValidationError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ValidationError):

Definition:

```py
class ValidationError(Exception):
    """An error while validating data."""

    def __init__(self, message, code=None, params=None):
        """
        The `message` argument can be a single error, a list of errors, or a
        dictionary that maps field names to lists of errors. What we define as
        an "error" can be either a simple string or an instance of
        ValidationError with its message attribute set, and what we define as
        list or dictionary can be an actual `list` or `dict` or an instance
        of ValidationError with its `error_list` or `error_dict` attribute set.
        """
        super().__init__(message, code, params)

        if isinstance(message, ValidationError):
            if hasattr(message, "error_dict"):
                message = message.error_dict
            elif not hasattr(message, "message"):
                message = message.error_list
            else:
                message, code, params = message.message, message.code, message.params

        if isinstance(message, dict):
            self.error_dict = {}
            for field, messages in message.items():
                if not isinstance(messages, ValidationError):
                    messages = ValidationError(messages)
                self.error_dict[field] = messages.error_list

        elif isinstance(message, list):
            self.error_list = []
            for message in message:
                # Normalize plain strings to instances of ValidationError.
                if not isinstance(message, ValidationError):
                    message = ValidationError(message)
                if hasattr(message, "error_dict"):
                    self.error_list.extend(sum(message.error_dict.values(), []))
                else:
                    self.error_list.extend(message.error_list)

        else:
            self.message = message
            self.code = code
            self.params = params
            self.error_list = [self]

    @property
    def message_dict(self):
        # Trigger an AttributeError if this ValidationError
        # doesn't have an error_dict.
        getattr(self, "error_dict")

        return dict(self)

    @property
    def messages(self):
        if hasattr(self, "error_dict"):
            return sum(dict(self).values(), [])
        return list(self)

    def update_error_dict(self, error_dict):
        if hasattr(self, "error_dict"):
            for field, error_list in self.error_dict.items():
                error_dict.setdefault(field, []).extend(error_list)
        else:
            error_dict.setdefault(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, []).extend(self.error_list)
        return error_dict

    def __iter__(self):
        if hasattr(self, "error_dict"):
            for field, errors in self.error_dict.items():
                yield field, list(ValidationError(errors))
        else:
            for error in self.error_list:
                message = error.message
                if error.params:
                    message %= error.params
                yield str(message)

    def __str__(self):
        if hasattr(self, "error_dict"):
            return repr(dict(self))
        return repr(list(self))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "ValidationError(%s)" % self

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ValidationError):
            return NotImplemented
        return hash(self) == hash(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        if hasattr(self, "message"):
            return hash(
                (
                    self.message,
                    self.code,
                    make_hashable(self.params),
                )
            )
        if hasattr(self, "error_dict"):
            return hash(make_hashable(self.error_dict))
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.error_list, key=operator.attrgetter("message"))))
```

Usage (from Django's repo):

```py
    def _clean_form(self):
        try:
            cleaned_data = self.clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.add_error(None, e)
        else:
            if cleaned_data is not None:
                self.cleaned_data = cleaned_data
```

```py
    def validate_unique(self):
        """
        Call the instance's validate_unique() method and update the form's
        validation errors if any were raised.
        """
        exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
        try:
            self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
        except ValidationError as e:
            self._update_errors(e)
```

```py
    def _update_errors(self, errors):
        # Override any validation error messages defined at the model level
        # with those defined at the form level.
        opts = self._meta

        # Allow the model generated by construct_instance() to raise
        # ValidationError and have them handled in the same way as others.
        if hasattr(errors, "error_dict"):
            error_dict = errors.error_dict
        else:
            error_dict = {NON_FIELD_ERRORS: errors}

        for field, messages in error_dict.items():
            if (
                field == NON_FIELD_ERRORS
                and opts.error_messages
                and NON_FIELD_ERRORS in opts.error_messages
            ):
                ...

            for message in messages:
                if (
                    isinstance(message, ValidationError)
                    and message.code in error_messages
                ):
                    message.message = error_messages[message.code]

        self.add_error(None, errors)
```

```py
    def add_error(self, field, error):
        """
        Update the content of `self._errors`.

        The `field` argument is the name of the field to which the errors
        should be added. If it's None, treat the errors as NON_FIELD_ERRORS.

        The `error` argument can be a single error, a list of errors, or a
        dictionary that maps field names to lists of errors. An "error" can be
        either a simple string or an instance of ValidationError with its
        message attribute set and a "list or dictionary" can be an actual
        `list` or `dict` or an instance of ValidationError with its
        `error_list` or `error_dict` attribute set.

        If `error` is a dictionary, the `field` argument *must* be None and
        errors will be added to the fields that correspond to the keys of the
        dictionary.
        """
        if not isinstance(error, ValidationError):
            # Normalize to ValidationError and let its constructor
            # do the hard work of making sense of the input.
            error = ValidationError(error)

        if hasattr(error, "error_dict"):
            if field is not None:
                ...
            else:
                error = error.error_dict
        else:
            error = {field or NON_FIELD_ERRORS: error.error_list}

        for field, error_list in error.items():
            if field not in self.errors:
                if field != NON_FIELD_ERRORS and field not in self.fields:
                    ...
                if field == NON_FIELD_ERRORS:
                    ...
                else:
                    self._errors[field] = self.error_class(renderer=self.renderer)
            self._errors[field].extend(error_list)
            if field in self.cleaned_data:
                del self.cleaned_data[field]
```

```py
    @property
    def errors(self):
        """Return an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form."""
        if self._errors is None:
            self.full_clean()
        return self._errors

    def is_valid(self):
        """Return True if the form has no errors, or False otherwise."""
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors
```

Also see the [Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/validators/) page