# How to list only down-most directories in Python?

Tags: python

```
import os

for dirpaths, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mydir):
    print dirpaths
```

gives me *all* (sub)directories in `mydir`. How do I get only the directories at the very bottom of the tree?

Comment: Recursively go all the way down and don't come back?

Comment: "very bottom" may not be meaningful depending on how you have your directories structured.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you show and example of a directory tree and the output you would like to achieve?

Comment: By 'very bottom' do you mean the end of each path tree?

Comment: It seems the OP means "leaf dirs" instead of "bottom-most dirs"--There is a distinction between the two.

Comment: Thanks you all (well, not all) for your comments. I didn't know about the distinction between bottom-most and leaf dirs. @Hai yes, I did try stuff -- I might not be smart, but am not lazy, thanks.

Comment: I am not accusing. In general, please show what you tried so people can help you.

Comment: I agree with @HaiVu. We don't judge or accuse on SO, but it makes our jobs a lot easier if you show us what you've attempted. That way, we are less vulnerable to misunderstandings from terminology (one of the questions was "what is a down-most directory?"); further, we might also be able to highlight where your implementation diverges from your spec. Posting your attempts is simply a tool to explain things better to you and also to show you where you may have gone wrong in the first place. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6470428/198633) as an example of how to formulate a question

Comment: @HaiVu: could you please expand on the distinction between bottom-most dirs and leaf dirs? I understood them to be the same, which according to your above comment is incorrect.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I tried to follow the guidelines with commonsense. And apparently it worked, since I got two spot on answers within minutes. Yes, I was vague on the definition of a "down-most" or "very bottom" dir. Yes, I could have spent an extra 5 mins building an example of what I was attempting, but most likely in my example leaf dirs would also be the deepest dirs, so both you and I would remain ignorant on this distinction. Some ambiguity sometimes is harmless -- and inevitable unless we are doing maths or physics, which we aren't.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: See my answer. Bottom most=leaf at max depth.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will print out only those directories that have no subdirectories within them

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mydir):
    if not dirnames:
        print dirpath, "has 0 subdirectories and", len(filenames), "files"
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
for dirpaths, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mydir):
    if not dirnames: print dirpaths
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw two solutions for showing leaf directories (i.e. those that does not contain sub-dir). Bottom-most directories, on the other hand, are not only leaf directories, but also are at the maximum depth. Here is a crude way to figure out the bottom-most directories:

```
import os

mydir = '/Users/haiv/src/python'
max_depth = 0
bottom_most_dirs = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mydir):
    depth = len(dirpath.split(os.sep))
    if max_depth < depth:
        max_depth = depth
        bottom_most_dirs = [dirpath]
    elif max_depth == depth:
        bottom_most_dirs.append(dirpath)
print bottom_most_dirs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

mydir='/home/'
print [dirpaths for dirpaths, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mydir) if not dirnames]
```