# Is it possible to catch multiple types of exceptions and then print the exact type that occurred?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

This is the [closest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block) I could find on catching multiple exceptions (the correct way), when after a miracle of acquiescence the interpreter allowed the following snippet:

```
try:
    x = "5" + 3
except NameError and TypeError as e:
    print e
```

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) would provide this snippet as well, but nothing like the former:

```
... except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
...     pass
```

So it would be nice to have a second opinion, but my question really comes down to this:

- How can I not only print the message, but insert at the beginning of the print statement the exact type of error raised. For example I would prefer the first snippet to respond by printing this instead: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

I feel like it probably is not possible, or easy, given that the interpreter lists only `args` and `message` as members of `NameError` but perhaps that is simply incomplete.

I have tried this myself, but it no longer excepts the errors (I might be misunderstanding isinstance):

```
try:
    x = "5" + 3
except (NameError, TypeError) as e:
    if isinstance(e, NameError):
        print "NameError: " + e
    elif isinstance(e, TypeError):
        print "TypeError: " + e
    else:
        print e
```

Comment: `type(e).__name__`? That might not be the best way, though.

Comment: @minitech That is genius, but I still do not know why my last snippet fails. I seem to misunderstand what I am doing.

Comment: It fails because you can not easily concat a string with an exception.

Comment: On the other hand, `print "NameError:", e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to concat a string with an exception like this

```
>>> 'foo' + TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'type' objects
```

The most simple workaround:

```
>>> 'foo' + str(TypeError)
"foo<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>"
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation, since `print e` is acceptable I got it in my mind it was a string! Not a smart thing to do on my part.

Comment: Why should an exception suddenly turn into a string? Weird idea!

Comment: "Prior to Python 1.5, standard exceptions were implemented as strings."(!) Source: _Core Python Programming_, 2nd Edition; Wesley J. Chun; Prentice Hall, 2007; Ch.10.5: _*Exceptions as Strings_. Exclamation mark added. ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can catch the errors individually. See this link for more examples:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Something like the following:

```
try:
    x = "5" + 3
except TypeError as e:
    print "This is a TypeError"
    print e
except NameError as e:
    print "This is a NameError"
    print e
```

Answer (score 8):

Others have answered your second question well, so I'll tackle your first one:

```
except NameError and TypeError as e:
```

is exactly the same as:

```
except TypeError as e:
```

It won't catch `NameError`. Why? Because `NameError` is truthy, so `and` evaluates and returns its second argument, `TypeError`. Try:

```
print NameError and TypeError
```

Yes, the exceptions in an `except` clause are *evaluated at runtime like any other expression.* In fact, Python doesn't even require that they be exceptions (however, if they're not, they won't ever catch anything because `raise` does require exceptions... well, you can use strings but they're deprecated).

For this reason you must provide a tuple of the exceptions to be caught:

```
except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
```

Other forms may be accepted by Python as valid syntax, but probably will not work as you might expect.

Answer (score 2):

Since minitech has already shown you the best way to do what you want (`print type(e).__name__`), I'll just cover what you've done wrong.

If `e = NameError("BAD, BAD, BAD!")`, then `print e` gives `BAD, BAD, BAD!`.

However, `"My string" + e` is not valid because `e` is not a string. Use `print "My string", e`, `print "My string" + str(e)` or `print "My string{}".format(e)` instead.