# try except within a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch

I'm having a problem with a `try except` within a `while` loop. I'm still relatively new to programming and this is part of my A2 Comp4 project.

```
def CheckValidInitials(initials):
    CheckIfTrue = False
    Count = 1
    while CheckIfTrue == False:
        while len(initials) == int(3) or len(initials) == int(4):
            listInitials = list(initials)
            print(len(initials))
            while len(listInitials) - Count >= 0:
                print(len(initials))
                print(len(listInitials) - Count)
                Count = Count + 1
                print(listInitials)
                try:
                    int(listInitials[Count])
                except IndexError and ValueError:
                    CheckIfTrue = True
                else:
                    print("One of your initials is a number, this is not valid")
                    print()
                    Count = 1
                    initials = input("Please enter valid initials: ")
                    listInitials = list(initials)

        else:
            initials = input("Please enter valid initials: ")
        return initials
```

I keep getting this error:

```
  File "D:\A2 Computing\Comp4\Prototype\Prototype Mk 3\TeacherInfo.py", line 105, in CheckValidInitials
    int(listInitials[Count])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My problem with this is that I thought I excepted `IndexError`'s in my `try except`. It is supposed to be throwing up this problem.

The overall code is supposed to be checking whether initials (entered in another function) contain any numbers.

Comment: `except OneException and AnotherException` isn't the right syntax for a catch block that handles multiple types of exceptions -- [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block)

Comment: O/T, but you should consider reading [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The syntax for multiple exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) is:

```
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
```

`and` is not a recognised part of this syntax; `IndexError and ValueError` evaluates to `ValueError`, so any `IndexError`s will not be caught.

Comment: `IndexError and ValueError` returns `ValueError` (the `and` operator returns the result of the right-hand expression if the left-hand expression is true-ish; type objects are always considered true)

Comment: Ah, there you go. Learned something new. :o)

Comment: Thanks @deceze  for this. There were a few other errors with my code but I've fixed them myself.

Again thanks for the help
Devilb77