# multiple try catch blocks in a loop

Tags: python, loops, exception

Am I being stupid for doing something like this? I feel like I may not fundamentally understand the purpose of `try catch` blocks.

I have a script that I want to run on auto-pilot on a daemon and what happens sometimes is that it checks to see if some resources in a list are fully allocated or not. If the resource is fully allocated it cannot continue with one thing, but there is other stuff it can do. Because I'm also calling something from an API, sometimes the `Exception` thrown by the API is very general (just like `API_Exception`). Is doing multiple `try` blocks pointless in this situation?

The main issue is that the `break` doesn't allow me to get out of the loop

```
for:
    try: 
         stuff()
    except ExceptionA:
         handle()
         break
    except ExceptionB:
         report()
         sys.exit()
    try:
         other_stuff()
    except ExceptionA:
         handle_in_a_different_way()
         break
    except ExceptionC:
         report()
         sys.exit()

other_code_that_should_execute_if_there_is_a_break()
```

In this case, should I be just combine these two blocks and catch `ExceptionA` once? `ExceptionA` might not have easily parseable parameters.

```
for:
    try:
        stuff()
        other_stuff()
    except ExceptionA:
        if ExceptionA has param
            handle()
        elif ExceptionA has other param
            handle_in_a_different_way()
    except ExceptionB:
        report()
        sys.exit()
    except ExceptionC:
        report()
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: you could group `except (ExceptionB,ExceptionC):` in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

I m not very experienced in exceptions, but I found something in the stack that may be helpfull.

[Catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6470428/7447240)

It also depends on which version you are currently using, in python 2 it seems you can use a comma to separate the exceptions, but in python 3 people advise to use 'as'to set them in a variable, then you could verify how to treat them