# How to call attribute if there are 2 error handling?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've tried couple ways and none solved my problem. Here is my code:

```
for i in links.readlines():
try:
    link = urlopen(i)
except (HTTPError, URLError) as e:
    print(e.code)
else:
    <Code Goes Here>
```

The error massage:

```
AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'code'
```

I need to make two Error Handling on one exception, but the problem I can't call the HTTPError attribute, I can't call the first Exception Handling at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle multiple exceptions with different except lines.

```
for i in links.readlines():
try:
    link = urlopen(i)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
except URLError as e:
    <do other handling here>
else:
    <Code Goes Here>
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block) for more details on exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for replied. I need all the exception on the same. So if the HTTPError code 405 and URLError SSL Verify Failed, The code will be lesser. If I make it two exception I need to add SSL Verify on the URLError.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTPError` is a subclass of `URLError`. The instance variable `code` is available in `HTTPError` and not in the base class `URLError`. Hence when you are trying to handle two errors in the same `except` block and when `URLError` occurs , the instance variable `code` is not found.

`URLError` has instance variable called `reason`, if you want to get the reason for the error.

In fact variable `reason` should be available for both the error types.
So instead of printing `e.code` print `e.reason` and you can achieve this using your own version of code.

```
for i in links.readlines():
    try:
        link = urlopen(i)
    except (HTTPError, URLError) as e:
        print(e.reason)
    else:
       <Code Goes Here>
```