# python import email_extractor syntax error on except

Tags: python, import, syntax, except

I'm trying to import email_extractor but get an error on the first except statement except `urllib2.URLError`, detail:

PyCharm message when editing that line says:

```
"Python 3.6 does not support this syntax"
```

How can I fix this please?

```
def getPage(url):
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        page = ""
        for i in f.readlines():
            page += i
        date = f.info().getdate('Last-Modified')
        if date == None:
            date = (0, 0, 0)
        else:
            date = date[:3]
        f.close()
        return (page, date, f.url)
    except urllib2.URLError, detail:
        pass
        return (None, (0,0,0), "")
```

Comment: somehow newline carriage returns were lost in my post ... sorry

Comment: the faulty line is

Comment: except urllib2.URLError, detail:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a wrong syntax with the `except` block, it should be with parenthesizes :

```
except (urllib2.URLError, detail):
    pass
    return (None, (0,0,0), "")
```