# except ConnectionError or TimeoutError not working

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

In case of a connection error, I want Python to wait and re-try. Here's the relevant code, where "link" is some link:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

from random import randint

try:
    r=requests.get(link)

except ConnectionError or TimeoutError:
    print("Will retry again in a little bit")
    time.sleep(randint(2500,3000))
    r=requests.get(link)
```

Except I still periodically get a connection error. And I never see the text "Will retry again in a little bit" so I know the code is not re-trying. What am I doing wrong? I'm pasting parts of the error code below in case I'm misreading the error. TIA!

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second request is not inside a try block so exceptions are not  caught.  Also in the try-except block you're not catching other exceptions that may occur.
You could use a loop to attempt a connection two times, and break if the request is successful.

```
for _ in range(2):
    try:
        r = requests.get(link)
        break
    except (ConnectionError, TimeoutError):
        print("Will retry again in a little bit")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    time.sleep(randint(2500,3000))
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this! Question: will this loop always sleep for 2500-3000 seconds or only if a connection error occurs? I want the latter, but it looks like this code is doing the former.

Comment: Only on error. If the request is successful the `break` statement  breaks the loop before `time.sleep` is called.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using a custom user agent in the request fixes this issue. With this method you spoof your browser.

Works:

```py
url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/amd"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Doesn't work:

```py
url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/amd"
response = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
except (ConnectionError, TimeoutError) as e:
    print("Will retry again in a little bit")
    time.sleep(randint(2500,3000))
    r=requests.get(link)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block) similar question, or check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: Thanks! What will "pass" do in this case? Cause the code under "try" to re-run again? Also, I do want to make the script wait a non-trivial amount before re-trying, and your suggestion doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: pass does nothing, you should replace it with your code. You should keep whatever code you have within the except block, i.e. your time.sleep call etc. I've edited my answer to use your code in the except block. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!  I updated my code and am re-running it just to make sure this fixed the issue.

Comment: Is there really a reason to assign an alias `e` in this case? You never use it again. `except (ConnectionError, TimeoutError):` will suffice.

Comment: I tried this version, and it didn't fix the issue. Still broke down on a Connection/TimeoutError without printing "Will retry again in a little bit" and re-trying.

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message? was the line that raised the error definitely in the try block? are you definitely catching the right type of error?

Comment: Yes, definitely catching the right error. I don't have the full error code anymore because the solution suggested by t.m.adam below is working. I agree it's weird that your approach didn't work because I thought this is how the syntax for try-except was supposed to work.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. It's not printing the retry statement ("Will retry again in a little bit"). The Exception text in e is "('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))" Is that not a TimeoutError?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out that urlib3 relies on socket.py, which raises an OSError. So, you need to catch that:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(link)
except OSError as e:
    print("There as an error: {}".format(e))
```