# Try / Catch syntax

Tags: python

Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57)
Pycharm 2017.3.3 Community build.

Newb question:

Is there a clean way to assign a group of exceptions to one variable, more than once, in an effort to give a two or more groups the same error?

```
a = 10
b = 0

try:
c=a/b

#except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError) as a:
#   raise Exception('The error was: %s’ %a)
except (NameError, MemoryError) as e:
    raise Exception('There is an error. The error is %s' %e)
```

When I uncomment the first exception I get:

```
File "<input>", line 8
raise Exception('The error was: %s’ %a)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

--Please forgive me if it's my syntax, but I just don't see it and this is a brand new language for me.  Thank you

Comment: Typo, downvote. Tip: **NEVER** copy code from other non-StackOverflow sites, especially ones with smart quotes.

Comment: [Not a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block).

Comment: No, it isn't. It is just a smart quote error. It should work fine with the smart quote replaced

Comment: <too localized>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your error: `raise Exception('The error was: %s’ %a)`. This line has smart quotes. The interpreter only recognises real quotes: `raise Exception('The error was: %s' %a)`

Comment: Thank you.  For my future reference, how does that happen?  I only see one button on the keyboard, only one type of single quote.

Comment: This happens because some editors autocorrect to curly quotes. What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using PyCharm