# Results won't be written into the txt file

Tags: python, file

Even though I'm using `file.flush()` at the end, no data will be written into the txt file.

```
# some essential code to connect to the server

while True:
    try:
        # do some stuff
        try:
            gaze_positions = filtered_surface['gaze_on_srf']
            for gaze_pos in gaze_positions:
                norm_gp_x, norm_gp_y = gaze_pos['norm_pos']

                if (0 <= norm_gp_x <= 1 and 0 <= norm_gp_y <= 1):
                    with open('/the/path/to/the/file.txt', 'w') as file:
                            file.write('[' + norm_gp_x + ', ' + norm_gp_y + ']')
                            file.flush()
                    print(norm_gp_x, norm_gp_y)
        except:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

What am I doing wrong? Obvisouly I miss something, but I can't figure it out, what it is. Another odd thing: there's even no output for `print(norm_gp_x, norm_gp_y)`. If I put the `with open ...` in a comment, I'll get the output.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your `if` statement ever evaluates to True and the `file.write` is ever executed? A [mcve] would help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes, I edited my question. Without writing something into the file, I'll get an output.

Comment: `except: pass` is a very lousy way of handling errors. If you don't get the print statement, that's because you got an exception.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez it does print an output.

Comment: What is: `#do some stuff`? It is needed in the question, because answerers need to be able to replicate the problem. Otherwise, you get `NameError: name 'filtered_surface' is not defined`, and that only if you get rid of the `try/except: pass`. If you don't remove that, you don't get anything, obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

got it:

First

```
if (0 <= norm_gp_x <= 1 and 0 <= norm_gp_y <= 1):
```

then:

```
file.write('[' + norm_gp_x + ', ' + norm_gp_y + ']')
```

So you're adding strings and integers. This triggers an exception, and since you used an universal `except: pass` construct, the code skips every iteration (note that this `except` statement also catches the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception you're trying to catch at a higher level, so that doesn't work either)

*Never* use that construct. If you want to protect about a specific exception (ex: IOError), use:

```
try IOError as e:
   print("Warning: got exception {}".format(e))
```

so your exception is 1) focused and 2) verbose. Always wait until you get exceptions that you want to ignore to ignore them, *selectively* (read [Catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block))

So the fix for your write it:

```
file.write('[{},{}]'.format(norm_gp_x, norm_gp_y))
```

or using the `list` representation since you're trying to mimic it:

```
file.write(str([norm_gp_x, norm_gp_y]))
```

Aside: your other issue is that you should use *append mode*

```
with open('/the/path/to/the/file.txt', 'a') as file:
```

or move you open statement before the loop, else you'll only get the last line in the file (a classic) since `w` mode truncates the file when opening. And you can drop `flush` since exiting the context closes the file.

Comment: Wow. Nicely spotted!

Comment: Yep. The exception handling it was. Already saw it in your comment and started to edit it in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed another thing: even though I put both `norm_gp_x` and `norm_gp_y` my txt file shows only twice the value for `norm_gp_x`? My output is correct, though.

Comment: hahaha there was a typo in my `format` parameters. The x variable was repeated, damn copy paste.