# Python 3 - dynamically catch unknown number of exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to write a decorator, where you could specify any number of exceptions to catch when calling a function (and then how to handle exception output for each exception). Now If I would know the number of exceptions, I could do just:

```
try:
    fun()
except SomeException1 as e:
    # handle
except SomeException2 as e:
    # handle
```

But let say I get list of exceptions.
`exceptions_to_handle = [SomeException1, SomeException2]`

Probably could do this, but maybe there is a better way?

```
try:
    fun()
except Exception as e:
    for exc in exceptions_to_handle:
        if isinstance(e, exc):
            # handle
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store *how to handle the exception* along with the list?

Comment: @user5173426 sure, but the question is not how to handle specific exception. It is how to catch it. I just written the reasoning why I need that.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block

Comment: Oh right. Forgot about that. Thanks