# How to handle multiple exception in a try block?

Tags: python, exception

Let's assume, a code consists of nearly 50 lines, and it has a `try` block. Consider a case that the `try` block has 10 unknown errors. Is it possible to handle those exceptions without specifying the name of the error in the `except` clause?

Here is the sample code:

```
try:
    a = 2
    b = 2 / 0
    if 7 > 5:
        print(7)
except(ZeroDivisionError, IndentationError)
    print("Exception Handled")
```

In the above case, I know the name of the errors that occurred in the try block(say- `ZeroDivisionError` and `IndentationError`)
What if the name of the error is unknown?

Comment: `except Exception` catches all exceptions

Comment: Note that in regards to @DeveshKumarSingh, you **usually** don't want to catch a general `Exception` because then you will have a rough time finding errors in your code.

Comment: yeah I tried it,But still i am getting run-time error

Comment: What did you try, add it to the question please, also you are missing a `:` in the except clause

Comment: As per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block - except (ZeroDivisionError, IndentationError) as e:
    # do stuff

Comment: I run the code, which i have mentioned above, by replacing except(ZeroDivisionError, IndentationError): with except Exception: But i am getting an Indentation error

Comment: @me_sarav Hello, here it runs. I will edit my answer for you

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
   #maliciousCodeFound
except:
   #catches ANY exception
```

except here Catches every error encountered in try block, you don't need to specify type of exception.
However, if you want to catch and handle a specific type of exception(eg. Arithmetic Exception), you might wanna use this to handle that specific case. Otherwise just use except.

Comment: It is bad practice to use a general `except`.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the exceptions you want to catch in a *tuple* like so:

```
try:
    a = 2
    b = 2 / 0
    if 7 > 5:
        print(7)
except (ZeroDivisionError, IndentationError) as e:
    print("Exception:", e)
```

Outputs: `Exception: division by zero`

Comment: My question is to handle the exception without specifying it in the except clause

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. AlmightyHeathcliff's answer is probably what you want. It catches ALL exceptions. What do you have in mind, though? "What if the name of the error is unknown" Why might it be unknown?

Answer (score 1):

### Exception hierarchy

Most exceptions are subclasses of the Exception class. But this is not true of all exceptions. Exception itself actually inherits from a class called BaseException. In fact, all exceptions must extend the BaseException class or one of its subclasses.

*Exception* derives directly from **BaseException** and the exceptions that we handle usually derive from *Exception*. There are two key exceptions, *SystemExit* and *KeyboardInterrupt*, that **derive directly** from BaseException instead of Exception. When we use the `except:` clause without specifying any type of exception, it will catch all subclasses of BaseException; which is to say, it will catch **all exceptions, including the two special ones**.

So, don't use `except:`, use:

```
try:
    # thing you want to try
except Exception:
    # handle exception
```

EDIT:

```
try:
    a = 2
    print("The next step the program will catch an exception.")
    b = 2 / 0
    if 7 > 5:
        print("This will never run.")
        print(7)
except Exception:
    print("Exception Handled")
```