# Python: How to catch a list of exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following:

```
exceptions: List[Exception]
exceptions = [ ValueError,TypeError,...]
```

And I would like to:

```
try: 
   # do something
   pass
except [e for e in exceptions]:
   # do something else
```

How would I do this?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block) can help

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270444/4996248) will help. It seems that `except tuple(exceptions)` should work.