# Python is not catching exception

Tags: python, exception, anaconda

This is my short code:

```
def loadImage(img_file):
    img = io.imread(img_file)           # RGB order
    if img.shape[0] == 2: img = img[0]
    if len(img.shape) == 2 : img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    if img.shape[2] == 4:   img = img[:,:,:3]
    img = np.array(img)

    return img
try:
    image = loadImage(filename)
except Exception as e:
   print("Error",e)
```

The image inside loadImage does not exist. So the error happens at this line `img = io.imread(img_file`. But Python is not catching it

Full error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text_ocr.py", line 393, in processFiles
    image = loadImage(filename)
  File "text_ocr.py", line 129, in loadImage
    img = io.imread(img_file)           # RGB order
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 48, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 210, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_plugins\imageio_plugin.py", line 10, in imread
    return np.asarray(imageio_imread(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 264, in imread
    reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 173, in get_reader
    request = Request(uri, "r" + mode, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 126, in __init__
    self._parse_uri(uri)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 278, in _parse_uri
    raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'D:\Program\OCR\test_ocr\3.png'
```

Comment: Have you tried `except FileNotFoundError:`?

Comment: No. But I think except Exception as e, catch all errors? Am I wrong?

Comment: Try it and see. Not every error is an exception.

Comment: It worked thanks. Is there any universal exception code?

Comment: Yes, you can write `except:` to catch everything.

Comment: Ahhhh..Thanks. How can I also print the error message?

Comment: I'm sure you can find the answer to that by searching this site.

Comment: Even `except:` does not work. Same error, same error traceback.

Comment: Only FileNotFoundError works. `except:` also does not work

Comment: I got another error inside the same function while reading file

Comment: ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'

Comment: Works for me, i get `Error module 'io' has no attribute 'imread'`. Seems a `Anaconda3` issue. Use: `except (FileNotFoundError, Exception) as e:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No. But I think except Exception as e, catch all errors? Am I wrong?

All built-in, `non-system-exiting` exceptions are derived from `Exception` class. All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.

However, The `FileNotFoundError` exception is subclasses of [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError).

Try this:

```
try:
    image = loadImage(filename)
except OSError as e:
   print("Error",e)
```

A small example code:

```
try:
    image = open("i_donot_exist")
except OSError as e:
   print("Exception Raised", e)
```

Outputs:

```
Exception Raised [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hehe'
```

> Any way to catch all types of errors? Programmer defined, built-in defined and all types on earth?

You need to put multiple `except` blocks to catch all type of exception. See an example below:

```
try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

You can also catch multiple exceptions in one line. 
From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a parenthesized tuple. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block) link for more information. For example,

```
try:
    may_raise_specific_errors():
except (SpecificErrorOne, SpecificErrorTwo) as error:
    handle(error) # might log or have some other default behavior...
```

Comment: Any way to catch all types of errors? Programmer defined, built-in defined and all types on earth?

Comment: I got another error at io.imread() line. `ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'`

Comment: How should I catch this?

Comment: No need for `except:`. If I use your last edit answer? Should I just put  `except (IOError, ValueError) as error:`

Comment: `except (OSError, ValueError) as e:`

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the whole traceback error with importing `tracaback` like this :

```
import traceback
try:
    #code that might produce error
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    pass
```

This actually doesn't catch the raised exceptions - the errors are shown in cli likewise if there were no try except block.