Python not logging my stored procedure error and success messages
Here is my code:
import os 
import json
import platform
import pymysql as pm
from datetime import date
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import logger

class LogOutput:
    env=None
    config=None

    def __init__(self, env_filename):
        self.env=env_filename
        self.config=self.get_config()
        

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)
        
    def is_Windows():
        if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
            return True
        else:
            return False       

    def setup_logger():
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        
        # Rotating log setup
        log_filename = f"E:\\here\\log\\file\\log-{date.today()}.log"
        file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_filename, when="midnight", backupCount=7)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        logger.addHandler(console_handler)
        return logger 
    setup_logger()

    def DB_connection(self):
        connection = None
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        try:
            config = self.get_config()
            host=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["host"]
            port=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["port"]
            database=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["db"]
            username=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["username"]
            password=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["password"]

            # Load the configuration from DB_conn_info_local.json
            config_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'DB_conn_info_local.json')
            with open(config_file_path) as config_file:
                config = json.load(config_file)

            connection = pm.connect(user=username,password=password,host=host,port=port,database=database)
    
            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection
    
    def logging_sp(self):
        logging_sp_query = """
        stored procedure code here
        """
        cnxn = self.DB_connection()
        if cnxn is None:
            logging.error("Database connection is None. Cannot proceed.")
            return  # Exit here if there's no valid connection
            
        with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
            try:
                cur.execute(logging_sp_query)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Unable to execute query: %s", e)        
            else:
                cnxn.commit()
        cnxn.close()  # Close the connection 


def main():
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
        vfc=(cwd+"\\DB_conn_info_local"+".json")
    else:
        vfc=(cwd+"/DB_conn_info_local"+".json")
    ve=LogOutput(vfc)
    ve.logging_sp()
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The part that isn't being written to the log file is here:
with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
    try:
        cur.execute(logging_sp_query)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unable to execute query: %s", e)        
    else:
        cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()  # Close the connection 

But I'm not sure why. I tried using logger.error, logger.info, logging.error, and I used the specific exception OperationalError as pm.err.OperationalError instead of Exception and it's not reading it. It's weird because this part of the code logger.info("Successfully connected to database") is being written to the logs and logging.info("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e)) part too, but not the part in the with statement.

Is this different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78971248/why-is-my-log-file-empty-in-my-python-script

no i reposted it with more work/things i have tried that haven't worked

The logger is not defined on your logging_sp function.
