# Using datetime with another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

My error-handling works, but something is wrong.

```
import datetime
def d(date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")


def test(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            value = input(prompt)
            a = d(value)
            break
        except ValueError or TypeError:
            print("Wrong format")
    return a

b = test("Write date")

def func():
    a = d(b)
    if d('1/12/2020') <= a <= d('28/02/2021'):
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("no")
```

func()

When I put `b` in another function I get:

```
return datetime.datetime.strptime(datumet, "%d/%m/%Y")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime.
```

But without error handling it works. What can be wrong with the code?

Comment: The error clearly comes from `func`, which you don't show us, so we can't help you. Either way, `datumet` is already `datetime` according to the error, so you don't need to call `strptime`

Comment: I will show you the function

Comment: What do you think is wrong?

Comment: You need to add error handling for `TypeError` somewhere — either in the `d()` function itself or everywhere an attempt is made to use it.

Comment: @martineau,  I placed: except ValueError or TypeError (in the test-function) but it did not work.

Comment: Without see what changes you made, I am unable comment further…

Comment: This `except ValueError or TypeError:` is not the correct way of catching multiple exceptions. See [Catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6470428/2745495).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test` function returns a datetime object. In the `func` function, you're trying to take the datetime object you've passed in and call the `d()` function on it, but `d()` expects a string as its input.

Look at this line:

```
b = test("Write date")
```

`b` is a datetime, because that's what `test` returned to it. Then when you call

```
func(b)
```

you're passing in that datetime. Then, inside `func` you have:

```
if d('1/12/2020') <= d(date) <= d('1/12/2021'):
```

The first call to `d('1/12/2020')` works because `d` expects to get a string. The second call, `d(date)` fails, because `date` isn't a string: it's the datetime you passed in. The third call to `d('1/12/2021')` *would* succeed but you're never getting that far because the second call fails.

Comment: I see so what should I do?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean!! But how should I fix the problem? I need to pass in parameter

Comment: You you _have_ to call `d(date)` inside `func` if it's already a datetime?

Comment: Do you mean like this? I edited the code? It still did not work

Comment: What happens if you try the comparison directly on the `date` value you pass into `func`, instead of trying to call `d(date)`?

Comment: It worked! thank you!!