# od.download() == None but it's not empty | Exception handling Opendatasets

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype

Update: turns out `od.download()` returns `None` by design.

**What might be better than a `None` check for `od.download()` *"failure"*?**

---

I am downloading a `.zip` file using `opendatasets` lib.

In `iris_scans()`; line `print(download)`, without the `if-statement` prints `None`.

However, at invocation `scans = iris_scans()` data is returned and subsequent prints can display data successfully.

---

The purpose of the `if-statement` is for "Graceful error handling".

**Note**: I've used an `if-statement` instead of `try-except` as there are many possibilities why `download == None` (e.g. dead link, connection interrupt etc.)

---

```
pip3 install opendatasets
```

```
import opendatasets as od
import zipfile
import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def iris_scans():
  download = od.download('http://www.mae.cuhk.edu.hk/~cvl/iris_database/iris_database.zip')
  """
  if download == None:
    print('Iris Scans - Link could not be established')
    return [[]*1778]
  """
  print(download)

  path_extract = 'iris_database/'
  with zipfile.ZipFile('iris_database.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(path_extract)
  
  os.remove(path_extract + 'readme.txt')
  
  filenames = os.listdir(path_extract)
  scans = []
  for f in filenames:
    img = Image.open(path_extract + f)
    #print("IMG", img)
    matrix = np.array(img)
    #print("MATRIX", matrix)
    scans.append(matrix)
  
  shutil.rmtree(path_extract)
  os.remove(path_extract[:-1] + '.zip')
  
  # Data Augmentation
  scans_90 = [np.rot90(s) for s in scans]
  scans_180 = [np.rot90(s) for s in scans_90]
  scans_270 = [np.rot90(s) for s in scans_180]

  scans_flip = [np.flip(s) for s in scans]
  scans_flip_90 = [np.rot90(s) for s in scans_flip]
  scans_flip_180 = [np.rot90(s) for s in scans_flip_90]
  scans_flip_270 = [np.rot90(s) for s in scans_flip_180]

  scans += scans_90
  scans += scans_180
  scans += scans_270

  scans += scans_flip_90
  scans += scans_flip_180
  scans += scans_flip_270

  return scans

scans = iris_scans()
print(scans[0])
print(len(scans))
```

Comment: Looking at the [source on Github](https://github.com/JovianML/opendatasets/blob/6a26edea54d6fbf15eb3cceda68d1bc7c1c4902f/opendatasets/utils/network.py), the function doesn't return anything, so it will always be None. I think you have to use a try/except statement.

Comment: Strange that it would by design... What is an alternative to `if download == None`, that isn't `try-except`? I would need to have many lines that each cover all possible error names in that case.

Comment: Or, for making `try-except`s, does that Github resource list all Error names anywhere? I cannot find them.

Comment: Looking at line 58 and 71 of the file I linked, it can raise either `urllib.error.URLError`, `IOError` or `RuntimeError`.

Comment: @Henry Refer to my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question was a road-block on the path of implementing some form of **Exception Handling** for the download.

`od.download() == None` by design; so an alternative to `if download == None` needed to be made.

As pointed out and assisted by @Henry; the below `Try-except` incorporates all exceptions found in the [Github source](https://github.com/JovianML/opendatasets/blob/6a26edea54d6fbf15eb3cceda68d1bc7c1c4902f/opendatasets/utils/network.py).

```
...
import urllib

def iris_scans():
  try:
    download = od.download('http://www.dgcdgyugcwyugyugcasc.com/wqduiuwqdwq') # BROKEN
    ...

    return scans
  
  except (urllib.error.URLError, IOError, RuntimeError) as e:
    print('Iris Scans - failed')
    return [[]*1778]
```

```
Iris Scans - failed
[]
1
```

Top answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block) demos many exceptions on one line.

Comment: That should work, to test exceptions use a non-existent URL as this should then raise an error.

Comment: I did that and: `File "main.py", line 57, in iris_scans
    except (URLError, IOError, RuntimeError) as e:
NameError: name 'URLError' is not defined`. Check answer for continual updates.

Comment: You need to `import urllib` at the start and change `URLError` to `urllib.error.URLError`

Comment: Tysm @Henry. God's gift on Earth.

Comment: Glad I could help :)