# Is it possible to use an "OR" logical operator in a Try/Exceptions Error handling in Python

Tags: python, try-catch, logical-operators

Suppose I have a code that uses the `try` and `except` clause to catch an error in Python as such :

```
try:
    some_action = print('Please answer my question')

except OSError:
    print("Error occured")
except ValueError:
    print("Error occured")
except BaseException:
    print("Error occured")
```

Is it possible to combine the `except` clauses using the `OR` logical operator in any way, for example in such a way :

```
try:
   some_action = print('Please answer my question')

except OSError or ValueError or BaseException:
   print ("Error occured")
```

I tried to look into the Python
[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) on the `except` clauses but I didn't find anything that could help me answer this question.

Perhaps it could be counter-intuitive to allow for `OR`, for Error handling, as one would prefer to do selective handling of exceptions, but I figured in some instances, using an `OR` operator could make the code slightly more elegant.

For example using the `OR` operator in an if/elif statements is possible :

```
for i in x:
    if A in i:
        pass
    elif B in i:
        pass
    elif C in i:
        pass
    else:
        print ('no A, B, or C in X')
```

which can be simplified into the following :

```
for i in x:
    if A in i or B in i or C in i:
       pass
    else:
       print ('no A, B, or C in X')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block)

Answer (score 1):

From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a parenthesized tuple, for example

```py
    except (OSError, ValueError) as e:
        pass
```

There is no sense for adding `BaseException` there, because it's a base class for all exceptions.

Comment: Well, it would make sense to either use `except (OSError, ValueError)` xor `except BaseError`