# How do you print an error with Try and Except

Tags: python

I feel stupid asking this since the answer is probably simple but I couldn't really find the answer by googling it... I have a lot of code which I don't want help with, I want to debug on my own, and I use try/except for it, but except doesn't print the error messsage and I couldn't find a way to print that. Basically, how do I check what my error is?

Comment: You can use `as`

Comment: You need to provide a code example all the same, for people to help - this doesn't have to be your full program, just write a simple example that causes an exception that you'd like to catch and explain the problem you're having with it. The solution should help in your actual code as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly to check what is your error, you can watch into your terminal there will be error's name:

```
print(5+"5")

>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\how_to_use_try_except.py", 
line 1, in <module>
    print(5+"5")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

and to catch it, you need to copy error's name, and except it

```
try:
    print(5+"5")
except TypeError:
    print("You can't add string value to int!")
```

also you can write

```
try:
    print(5+"5")
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
>>>
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `traceback`, more specifically `traceback.print_exc()`. This prints the full error traceback, rather than just the one line produced from using `as` in your `except` block.

I've put an example below using a `ValueError`.

```
import traceback

try:
    int("s")
except ValueError:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

This produces the same print result as if there was no try-except, the difference being that this solution allows the code to continue running.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use try except to catch ANY error without worrying for its types.
Use this code

```
try:
    blah blah
except Exception as A: #(Where A is a temporary variable)
    print(a)
```

Tadaaa, you just captured the error without blowing your whole code.

Comment: I already know that but I need the things in the try function to run, I needed to know what the error type was to find out what I needed to fix

Comment: python is case sensitive so "A" and "a" are treated differently