# Python try/except flow if multiple except blocks are True

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-requests, try-catch

I would like to set "errored" to False if the exception is a Timeout error. I'm a little confused how try except flows work in python here (and surprisingly couldn't find any doc clarifying this - if anyone has one regarding how the blocks are executed please feel free to link), like if multiple exception blocks are true, do they all execute? Or just the first one? I assume the below doesn't work because we don't have access to 'r'

```
try:
    r = request(
        method="POST",
        ...
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    resp = r.json()
    errored = False

except Exception as e:
    resp = _parse_json(e)
    errored = True
    if r.Timeout:
        errored = False
```

And the below is the effect I want, just not sure if it works as intended with the try/except flow

```
try:
    r = request(
        ...
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    resp = r.json()
    errored = False

except Exception as e:
    resp = _parse_json(e)
    errored = True

except r.Timeout:
    errored = False
```

This is my first time handling/making post requests so please bear with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've researched, in python the flow falls on the first except that matches the exception. In this case, place the timeout exception first.

```
import socket
import logging

errored = False
hostname = '10.255.255.1'
port = 443
socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.1)
try:
    sock = socket.create_connection((hostname, port))

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('must not enter here')

except socket.timeout as err:
    print('timeout')
    errored = False
except Exception as ex:
    print('base exception')
    errored = True
except:
    print('unknown exception')
    errored = True
else:
    print('success')
finally:
    print('This is always executed')
```

This code example makes a request that will timeout, will always fall into

```
except socket.timeout as err:
```

and then in finally.
you can change the order of except to test.

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp#:%7E:text=The%20try%20block%20lets%20you,the%20try%2D%20and%20except%20blocks.) a link about trycatch.

Hope this helps

Comment: I just found something that might complement my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block?rq=1