# Is this a valid pythonic code to use multiple exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

Say we have code like this.

```
try:
    v = the_dict[the_key]
    i = int(v)
    print(f"Converted integer is {i}")

except KeyError:
    print(f"the_dict doesn't have key {the_key}")

except ValueError:
    print(f"It is {v}")
```

For the second except block, can we say because KeyError was not caught so **v** variable must be valid?

Is this a pythonic way to use multiple exceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: In addition, in this specific case, the dictionary `.get` method removes the need to catch the key error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch multiple exceptions in one line (except block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle both `KeyError` and `ValueError`, you might want to nest the try-except blocks

Here's updated code:

```
try:
    v = the_dict[the_key]
    try:
        i = int(v)
        print(f"Converted integer is {i}")
    except ValueError:
        print(f"It is {v}")
except KeyError:
    print(f"the_dict doesn't have key {the_key}")
```

Your code is on the right track, but you need to consider the scoping of the variables in the context of the exceptions being caught.