# a program to store information about a single user

Tags: python

a program to store information about a single user.  The program should include a function that asks the user for their name, age, course, and home town and stores this in memory.  It should also have a function that will write the information entered in a file.   Use exception handling to protect the data entry and the file operations

really stuck on this any help would be great

Comment: Please put examples of what you have tried in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name=raw_input("Enter name :")
surname=raw_input("Enter surname :")

n=None
while n is None:
    age=raw_input("Enter age :")
    try:
        n = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a number."

course=raw_input("Enter course :")
hometown=raw_input("Enter hometown :")



with open("workfile","w") as f:
    f.write('Name : ' + name + '\n')
    f.write('Surname : ' + surname + '\n')
    f.write('Age : ' + str(age) + '\n')
    f.write('Course : ' + course + '\n')
    f.write('Hometown : ' + hometown + '\n')


f.close()
```

for exception handling in file I/O see [What is a good way to handle exceptions when trying to read a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627425/what-is-a-good-way-to-handle-exceptions-when-trying-to-read-a-file-in-python)